# Remove everything after a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to remove everything after a certain character or just choose everything up to that character?  I'm getting the value from an href and up to the "?", and it's always going to be a different amount of characters.

Like this

```
/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444
```

I want the href to be `/Controller/Action` only, so I want to remove everything after the "?".

I'm using this now:

```
 $('.Delete').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var id = $(this).parents('tr:first').attr('id');                
     var url = $(this).attr('href');

     console.log(url);
 }
```

Answer (score 598, accepted):

You can also use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function. This seems to be the easiest one that comes to my mind :).

```
url.split('?')[0]
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LmLW/)

One advantage is this method will work even if there is no `?` in the string - it will return the whole string.

Comment: what does the [0] do in this situation?

Comment: `split` returns an array (in this case it has two elements, `0` and `1`), and `[0]` gets the first element of the returned array.

Comment: +1, best thing about this is that it always works, even if there is no '?'

Comment: what should we do if we want to split '\' ?

Comment: Love this answer, so simple and yet really powerful in what it gives you

Comment: I actually changed the answer to this as it is more flexible and just a cleaner solution overall.

Comment: Is there a way to do this where it doesn't include the given character in the removal? Say I want to remove everything after 'wednesday', if I do split('y'), it gives me wednesda.

Comment: You can optimize the answer a bit by adding the limit argument to the split function: `url.split('?', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 536):

```
var s = '/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444';
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('?'));
document.write(s);
```

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/L4hna/)

I should also mention that native string functions are much faster than regular expressions, which should only really be used when necessary (this isn't one of those cases).

Updated code to account for no '?':

```
var s = '/Controller/Action';
var n = s.indexOf('?');
s = s.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
document.write(s);
```

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/L4hna/1/)

Comment: this spaghetti code should not be the best answer.  see the split method answer

Comment: LoL - Somehow those not understand regex and how split works got the voting powers. Understanding the String methods is enough. Least understanding how things works and largest code rules the world :P So I added a step by step explanation to the split answer (to change the wolrd).

Comment: LoL - The split can accept regex so +1 for not using split? LoL - Javascript use regex so +1 for not using Javascript? How can more code and complexity make it a simple task? Isn't both regex and split simpler and more effective?

Comment: @LastTribunal I actually changed the answer today. The split is more flexible and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 39):

```
var href = "/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444";
href = href.replace(/\?.*/,'');
href ; //# => /Controller/Action
```

This will work if it finds a '?' and if it doesn't

Comment: this will just remove the '?' and some others to OP didn't ask for

Comment: This will remove everything after the `?` (included)

Comment: **BEST ANSWER**! OP asked for remove EVERYTHING after `?` and clearly stated to remove `?` also by say: ***I want the href to be /Controller/Action only***

Answer (score 13):

May be very late party :p

You can use a back reference [**$'**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

```
$' - Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
```

```js
let str = "/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444"

let output = str.replace(/\?.*/g,"$'")

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This answer was useful for my application. In particular, if a pattern of some kind is at the end of a string, you can remove it with $'.

Answer (score 7):

It works for me very nicely:

```
var x = '/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444';
var remove_after= x.indexOf('?');
var result =  x.substring(0, remove_after);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `split()` method which, to me, is the easiest method for achieving this goal.

For example:

```js
let dummyString ="Hello Javascript: This is dummy string"
dummyString = dummyString.split(':')[0]
console.log(dummyString)
// Returns "Hello Javascript"
```

Source: https://thispointer.com/javascript-remove-everything-after-a-certain-character/

Comment: Already the author kapa has given the proper answer using split. Here there is not much difference compared to his answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you also want to keep "?" and just remove everything *after* that particular character, you can do:

```
var str = "/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444",
    stripped = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('?') + '?'.length);

// output: /Controller/Action?
```

Comment: This does not work if the string does not contain a `?`

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Yes I know. Since my answer says: "if you also want to keep the *?* " - there obviously has to be a question mark in the string to keep..

Comment: Strange, seems my comment was meant for the other answer by @Imran. Don't know why I posted it on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you add some json syringified objects, then you need to trim the spaces too... so i add the trim() too.

```
let x = "/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444";
let result =  x.trim().substring(0,  x.trim().indexOf('?'));
```

Comment: This will remove spaces at the beginning of the string as well, which was not in the question.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
      var first = regexLabelOut.replace(/,.*/g, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

It can easly be done using JavaScript for reference see link
[JS String](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jstring1.htm)

EDIT 
it can easly done as. ;)

```
var url="/Controller/Action?id=11112&value=4444 ";
var parameter_Start_index=url.indexOf('?');
var action_URL = url.substring(0, parameter_Start_index);
alert('action_URL : '+action_URL);
```