# jquery remove everything after and including certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a location - `Pearl River, NY (10965)` that I want displayed as `Pearl River, NY` (so it must delete `(10965)` -- including the space before `(` -- I'm not looking to make a big deal of this and do anything server side. jQuery would work fine. I know this is probably simple as hell, I just don't use JS much.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5631384/425313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location_string = location_string.replace(/ \([^)]*\)/, '');
```

On a side note, please stop thinking that jQuery is necessary for anything at all, especially not a string manipulation task like this. It really isn't, and jQuery is overhyped.

Comment: +1 for not needing to use jQuery. -1 for saying jQuery is overhyped.

Comment: I believe it is, though. It is completely unnecessary for most applications, and it is overused.

Comment: I note that the `+` would leave in empty brackets `()`. This could well be acceptable, however.

Comment: It doesn't leave empty brackets, as far my testing shows. Run this in a browser console: `'Pearl River, NY (10965)'.replace(/ \([^)]+\)/, '');`

Comment: Delan: I think @James is talking about `'Pearl River, NY ()'.replace(/ \([^)]+\)/, ''); === "Pearl River, NY ()"` rather than `'Pearl River, NY ()'.replace(/ \([^)]+\)/, ''); === "Pearl River, NY"`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So `*` would be a better quantifier than `+`.

Comment: Yuo might also want to stipulate that it occurs at the end of a string, hence you would add a `$` at the end as per the second sample below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're given "Peal River NY..." (variable? innerHTML?), but you need to use a regular expression to match the `(numbers)`, and the `replace` method to substitute the match for nothing `""`.

```
"Peal River, NY (10965)".replace(/ \([0-9]+\)/, "");
```

This doesn't use jQuery!

See the [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

As mentioned by @James in the comments, this snippet will leave "Peal River, NY ()" as "Peal River, NY ()", rather than removing the brackets. If this is a case you need to consider, change the `+` to `*`:

```
"Peal River, NY (10965)".replace(/ \([0-9]*\)/, "");
```

Comment: I note that the `+` would leave in empty brackets `()`. This could well be acceptable, however.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```
var s = "Pearl River, NY (10965)";
alert(s.replace(/ \([\d]*\)/,''));
```

See it at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EU9Qm/)

Of course, here I am assuming you'll be wanting to replace only numbers in the brackets. For letter and underscore, use `\w` in place of `\d`

You might also want to make it a requirement that the item occurs at the end. In which case, the following will suffice:

```
alert(s.replace(/ \([\d]*\)$/,''));
```

You'll note that none of the above references jQuery. This is something that can be achieved with pure JavaScript.