# How to remove symbol and everything after this symbol from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys i want to know how can i remove a symbol and everything after that symbol from a string with jQuery or JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
var optionValueText = $.trim($('[data-divNumber="on"] :selected').text());
```

The variable `optionValueText` is printing results like `My first result +24.00 euros`

So what i want to do is to remove everyting after the `+` plus symbol including the plus symbol itself.

So for final result of my example i want to receive a result like this `My first result` and that is it!

How can i make it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jhf9teb/1/)**

Use

```
optionValueText = optionValueText.substring(0, optionValueText.indexOf('+'));
alert(optionValueText);
```

Explanation : Find index(character position) of + and take substring from 0 till that index of + .

For more info read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character)