# How to remove everything after particular character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string which is as below :

```
Documents for 047-428583 > FOLDER A > FOLDER D
```

I want to remove `> FOLDER D` while doing a particular operation.

I have tried using substring which is as below but it removes everything after `>`

```
 var data = $("#extend").text();
 $("#extend").text(data.substring(0, data.indexOf('>')));
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character) but in my case i have multiple same characters so i can not use that. I guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lastIndexOf instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

```
$("#extend").text(data.substring(0, data.lastIndexOf('>') - 1));
```

Comment: Perhaps lastIndexOf-1 for the extra space

Comment: And `.slice` is usually  preferred over `.substring`. For instance does `.slice` support `"abc".slice(0, -1) == "ab"`

Comment: Well substring can't bake me cookies either but its still fine for sub strings

Answer (score 2):

You could split the `text()` value by the `>` character and then remove the final element in the resulting array:

```
$("#extend").text(function(i, val) {
    var arr = val.split('>');
    arr.pop();
    return arr.join(' > ');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0r2xLrz4/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can split and then join again:

```
 var data = $("#extend").text().split('>').pop();
 data.join(" > ");
```

## EDIT

As the comment said, pop() method returns the final string and this code is no correct. The correct answer is that @Rory McCrossan writes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31674474/5035890

Comment: This will error - `data` will be a string with no `join` method.

Comment: It's true, pop() method returns the final string. Your answer is better, but we answer at the same time :D

Comment: No problem :) It would be best to edit your answer so that it's correct though.