# Javascript convert number

Tags: javascript, regex

For instance I have this number: 1.000,20 I want to convert it to 1000.20 or just remove everything behind the comma like this: 1000.

How do I achieve this? I did this:

```
console.log(num3.replace(/\[,.]/g, ''), 'test', num3.replace(/\,/g, ''));
```

Which results in: 0,00

Here is a Fiddle which console.logs the output on line 18 in the JS: https://jsfiddle.net/kn7ae9e2/1/

Comment: See [Remove everything after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character)

Comment: When you say "I have a number", I guess what you mean is **"I have a *string*"**?? Also, converting "1.000,20" --> "1000" is *not*  only removing after the comma, you have also removed the `"."`. Is that also desired/intentional? Do you want the final result to be a *string* or a *number*? Please be very specific in what you are asking; this is too vague and open to interpretation.

Comment: `num3.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/, '.')` ?

Comment: Please explain the question with proper number formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **replace** the `.` first and then **match** everything before `,`

```
"1.000,20".replace(/\./g, "").match(/\d+(?=,)/) //prints 1000
```

**Demo**

```js
var output = "1.000,20".replace(/\./g, "").match(/\d+(?=,)/) //prints 1000
console.log( output );
```

Comment: This results: null it is indeed a string like tomLord mentions above than I tried this: Number(num3.replace(/\./g, "").match(/\d+(?=,)/g)) but this results in 0

Comment: @Sreinieren I have attached a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string and recombine it like so:

```
num3="1.000,20";
num3.split(',')[0].split('.').join('') //"1000"
```

You can prepend it with the unary `+` operator to typecast it to a number

```
+num3.split(',')[0].split('.').join('') ///1000
```

If you want to preserve the value after the decimal point, you can do something like this:

```
function parseNumber(str){
    var splits = str.split(',');
    var preDec = splits[0].split('.').join('');
    return splits.length > 1? +(preDec+'.'+splits[1]): +preDec;
}

parseNumber("1.000,20"); //1000.2
```