# How to remove text on a web page before or after a specific character

Tags: jquery, css

I have on a *WordPress* site a list of headlines followed by a source attribution, a date and an excerpt. I want to keep the headline, the source attribution and the date but want to get rid of everything after either 'am' or 'pm' in the date (the excerpt). Is there a way to do that?

**Example:**

*NBA Finals:* Warriors will face Cavaliers yet again

*USA Today* – NBA | May 29, 2018 5:39 am Sports Pulse: USA TODAY Sports’ Sam Amick breaks down the Warriors’ Game 7 win over the Rockets, and how they’ll match up in a fourth consecutive.

**HTML containing the content:**

```html
<div class="entry-content cf" itemprop="text">
  <div class="entry-excerpt">
    <p>
    Boston Herald &#8211; Boston Celtics | May 29, 2018 8:47 am Here we go again. And again. And, well, again. Round 4 &mdash; as many predicted, and others probably lamented &mdash; is happening. Cleveland and Golden
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS wise, no, This is a javascript update most likely. Also one issue you may want to consider is, if you have 'am' or 'pm'. part of the title before the time for example.. 'Amar Miller commits to Mineral Area College | May 29, 2018 5:39 am' then your title will only show 'Am' Does that make sense?

Comment: 1. Do you want to hide everything after am/pm or do you not want php to output it at all? 2. If you just want to hide it can you show us the html of your target content including the parent container. It may be possible with just css. If not it will require some javascript.

Comment: </div>

<div class="entry-content cf" itemprop="text" >
 
 
  <div class="entry-excerpt"><p>Boston Herald &#8211; Boston Celtics | May 29, 2018 8:47 am Here we go again. And again. And, well, again. Round 4 &mdash; as many predicted, and others probably lamented &mdash; is happening. Cleveland and Golden</p>
</div>
Hi Hastig, this is the html of my target content. I do just want to hide everything after 'am' or 'pm'.
 
 </div>

Comment: Thanks Ben. It would indeed not make sense if part of the title contained 'am' or 'pm' before the time. Perhaps you could say there is a space on either side of 'am' and 'pm'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you are using jQuery.
https://jsfiddle.net/andreitodorut/t4fvqoyw/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.title').each(function() {
    $(this).text(
        $(this).text().substr(0,
          $(this).text().indexOf(" am") > -1 ?
             $(this).text().indexOf(" am") + 3 :
             $(this).text().indexOf(" pm") + 3)
    )
  })

});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. That does indeed work. Can you tell me where I would need to insert this code on my site. I'm afraid I am a complete novice. If it helps, the headlines and excerpts are being generated by a  WordPress plug-in called WP-RSS-Aggregator. Would I need to insert this into the source code of the plug-in, or could I insert it using the theme editor in WordPress? Thanks!

Comment: you have to insert in .js file within your theme

Answer (score 0):

Another javascript/jQuery option (there's probably a lot of better ways)..

```js
$('.entry-excerpt').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).find('p').text();
  if ($(this).find('p').is(':contains(" am ")')) {
    amString = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(' am '));
    $(this).find('p').text(amString + ' am');
  } else if ($(this).find('p').is(':contains(" pm ")')) {
    pmString = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(' pm '));
    $(this).find('p').text(pmString + ' pm');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-excerpt">
  <p>
  NBA Finals: Warriors will face Cavaliers yet again

  USA Today – NBA | May 29, 2018 5:39 am SportsPulse: USA TODAY Sports’ Sam Amick breaks down the Warriors’ Game 7 win over the Rockets, and how they’ll match up in a fourth conseuctive
  </p>
</div>
<div class="entry-excerpt">
  <p>
  Boston Herald &#8211; Boston Celtics | May 29, 2018 8:47 pm Here we go again. And again. And, well, again. Round 4 &mdash; as many predicted, and others probably lamented &mdash; is happening. Cleveland and Golden
  </p>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/o8hedrsk/

**credit**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5631434/3377049