# Remove Everything After Certain Character Within String Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

**EDIT**: My code *does* work - I just had a typo when I was `console.logging`. It uses the same technique already found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character).

I have a function that should remove everything after the comma in the string:

```
function shortenToDate(longDate) {

  let newDate = longDate.substring(0, longDate.indexOf(","));

  return newDate;

}
```

^ You just need to take a chunk out of the string from the 0 index to the `indexOf()` the first instance of whatever character you wish to remove everything after.

I had also tried:

```
function shortenToDate(longDate) {

  return longDate.substring(longDate.indexOf(0, ","));

}

console.log(shortenToDate(shortenToDate("Friday May 2, 9am")));
```

Which didn't have any effect. It just returned `Friday May 2, 9am`.

Comment: Regarding your second snippet: *"And that didn't return anything"*... it clearly does: https://jsfiddle.net/wxprm41z/

Comment: Here is an image to show you (answering to your now deleted comment): https://imgur.com/UZTF6Be.

Comment: So then my second guess was actually working. I don't know why it wasn't logging anything to the console before.

Comment: Yes, it was working. So, at the end, your question was unnecessary! What strikes me the most is that 3 high-rep users saw your question, saw that you had a working code (I hope so...) but, instead of voting to close and leave you a comment, decided to write an answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm going to go ahead and delete this question. The question that I linked already has the correct answer with `(0, longDate.indexOf(","))`.

Comment: Apparently you can't delete if others have already provided answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use split and take the 0<sup>th</sup> index

```js
const shortenToDate = longDate => longDate.split(',',1)[0];
console.log(shortenToDate("Friday May 2, 9am"))
```

Problems

In the first snippet you're using

```
longDate.substring(longDate.indexOf(","), longDate.length -1);
```

but you want from 0<sup>th</sup> index

```js
const  shortenToDate = longDate => longDate.substring(0,longDate.indexOf(","));

console.log(shortenToDate("Friday May 2, 9am"))
```

Comment: That is what I was doing in my second snippet. I don't know why it wasn't logging anything to the console. That code is correct, then.

Answer (score 2):

How about that with [String​.prototype​.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.prototype​.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)?

```js
function shortenToDate(longDate) {
  let newDate = longDate.split(',');
  return newDate.shift();
}

console.log(shortenToDate("Friday May 2, 9am"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to use a regular expression - match a comma, followed by any characters, and replace with the empty string:

```js
const shortenToDate = longDate => longDate.replace(/,.*/, '');
console.log(shortenToDate("Friday May 2, 9am"))
```

Comment: Why the downvote, did I make a mistake somewhere? Please let me know, I'll be happy to fix it!