# How to remove 9 characters from the end of the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I remove the characters at the end of my strings " - number" from divs using javascript

I need to remove 9 characters from the end of the string and I can't figure it out

```
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Building and Construction (Management) – 597007</a></div>
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Electronics and Communications Engineering - 597292</a></div>
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Engineering - 596942</a></div>
```

should look like:

```
Advanced Diploma of Building and Construction (Management)
Advanced Diploma of Electronics and Communications Engineering
Advanced Diploma of Engineering
```

I would really appreciate someone's help, I've been trying to figure this out for ages now

Comment: `str.slice(0, -9)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove everything after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character)

Comment: I really appreciate the response! How do I apple that function to the div element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice`:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.course_title a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].innerText = links[i].innerText.slice(0, -9);
}
```

```html
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Building and Construction (Management) – 597007</a></div>
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Electronics and Communications Engineering - 597292</a></div>
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Engineering - 596942</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each div using .forEach(), then use `.slice()` to edit the text.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".course_title").forEach(function(course) {
  course.innerText = course.innerText.slice(0, -9);
})
```

Comment: -9 to remove the space char.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't use `forEach` with `querySelectorAll`, so here's a revised answer from the above.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".course_title a")

for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerText = elements[i].innerText.slice(0, -9)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by taking advantage of 2 `String.prototype` methods: `lastIndexOf` and `substring`.

Here's an example:

```js
const formattedHtml = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).reduce((html, el) => {
  const anchorText = el.innerText;

  html += `<div class="course_title"><a>${anchorText.substring(0, anchorText.lastIndexOf('-')).trim()}</a><div class="course_title">`;

  return html;
}, '');

document.querySelector('#target').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', formattedHtml);
```

```html
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Building and Construction (Management) - 597007</a></div>
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Electronics and Communications Engineering - 597292</a></div>
<div class="course_title"><a>Advanced Diploma of Engineering - 596942</a></div>

<br />
<div id="target">

</div>
```