# String Remove Everything after Last Hyphen

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in JavaScript to remove everything after last hyphen if its a number?

```
product-test-grid-2
```

So Result would be only:

```
product-test-grid
```

Trying to use this resource:

[Remove everything after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character)

Comment: `words=sentence.split("-");
if(words[words.length-1].match(/^\d+$/)) words.pop();
result=words.join("-");`

Comment: @alansmith4785 run the code in my answer for a pure JS working solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression with replace.

eg..

`/-\d+$/`   = a dash followed by 1 or more numbers `\d+`, that's at the end `$`

```js
const reLast = /-\d+$/;
const test1 = 'product-test-grid-2';
const test2 = 'product-test-grid-nan';

console.log(test1.replace(reLast, ''));
console.log(test2.replace(reLast, ''));
```

Comment: @alansmith4785  Yes, I've altered the snippet to show one without a number, `nan`..

Answer (score 3):

Simple JS, No regex involved

```js
const label = 'product-test-grid-2'.split('-');
!isNaN(+label[label.length - 1]) ? label.pop() : '';
console.log(label.join('-'));


// you can encapsulate it into function
function formatLabel(label) {
  label = label.split('-');
  !isNaN(+label[label.length - 1]) ? label.pop() : '';
  return label.join('-');
}


// 2 should be removed at the end
console.log(formatLabel('product-test-grid-2'));

// two should be left untouched
console.log(formatLabel('product-test-grid-two'));
```

Comment: You say that like regex is a bad thing.. :),  might be worth pointing out the regex version is over 5 times faster.

Comment: @Keith I didn't say regex is bad, it's just overkill for this simple task, IMHO performance consideration for this will come under micro-optimization which a beginner OP shouldn't be needlessly engaged with

Comment: If OP needed to catch something like phone number based on a format from web page or a geographic location then I would have surely recommended regex for that task

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you have done, its good to see different ways of doing the same thing.  But why is`/-\d+$/` overkill?.  As a function it's just `const formatLabel = label => label.replace(/-\d+$/,'')`  Like I say, nothing wrong with what you have done, but seemed a bit weird saying `No regex involved`, it would be a bit like me saying `no arrays involved`.. :)

Comment: @Metabolic, interesting use of ternary.
Do you think that a simple `if` could be, well, simpler, and more obvious?
(up-voted)

Answer (score 2):

`'product-test-grid-2'.replace(/(?<=-)\d*$/, '')` will preserve the last hyphen.

`'product-test-grid-2'.replace(/-\d*$/, '')` will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Split by "-", check if last item is a number: pop if it is, join with "-":

```js
sentence="product-test-grid-2";
words=sentence.split("-");
if(words[words.length-1].match(/^\d+$/)) words.pop();
result=words.join("-");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `regrx` but it seems to me Overkill

I would do that

```js
    const str='product-test-grid-2'
    const pos=str.lastIndexOf('-')
    const res=str.slice(0,pos)
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: @alansmith4785  Yes, It gives you the last position of the specific character

Comment: @Yoel your answer doesn't check if the last character is a number or not